# socket connection between matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, sockets, heroku, tcp

I wrote the following code in matlab and python. I am using heroku server created by python as a client and matlab as server.

MATLAB code:

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0',4000,'NetworkRole','Server')  
fopen(t)  
data = fread(t,t.BytesAvailable)  
fwrite(t,'hello back')
```

Python Code:

```
TCP_IP = 'my_laptop_ip_address'
TCP_PORT = 4000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE="Hello World"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

return "received data:",data
```

When I run the MATLAB code and then after the server is open I run the test function from heroku, my page keeps loading and doesnt connect with MATLAB server.

Answer (score 0):

The `TCP_IP` variable in the python client should hold the server's IP address, not your laptop address.

Comment: I have created the server on my laptop using matlab. Isn't the IP address same?

Comment: So is the python client on Heroku and the matlab server in you laptop?

Comment: yes, I have created a web python heroku app as a client and matlab server on my laptop.